# Playing YUV video with SDL: Line wraps too late when resolution is not multiple of 4

Tags: c, sdl, yuv

I've been battling with an issue when playing certain sources of uncompressed YUV 4:2:0 planar video data with `SDL_Overlay` (SDL 1.2.5).

I have no problems playing, say, **640x480** video. But I have just attempted playing a video with the resolution **854x480**, and I get a strange effect. The line wraps 1-2 pixels too late (causing a shear-like transformation) and the chroma disappears, to be replaced with alternating R, G or B on each line. See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzIQI.jpg)

The YUV data itself is correct, as I can save it to a file and play it in another player. It is not padded at this point - *the pitch matches the line length.*

My suspicion is that some issue occurs when the resolution is not a multiple of 4. Perhaps `SDL_Surface` expects an `SDL_Overlay` to have a chroma resolution as a multiple of 2?

Adding to my suspicion, I note that the RGB `SDL_Surface` that I create at a size of **854*480** has a pitch of **2564**, not the **3*854 = 2562** I would expect.

If I add 1 or 2 pixels to the width of the `SDL_Surface` (but keep the overlay and rectangle the same), it works fine, albeit with a black border to the right. Of course this then breaks with videos which **are** a multiple of four.

#### Setup

```
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(width, height, 24, SDL_SWSURFACE|SDL_ANYFORMAT|SDL_ASYNCBLIT);
if ( screen == NULL ) {
  return 0;
}
YUVOverlay = SDL_CreateYUVOverlay(width, height, SDL_IYUV_OVERLAY, screen);
Ydata = new unsigned char[luma_size];
Udata = new unsigned char[chroma_size];
Vdata = new unsigned char[chroma_size];

YUVOverlay->pixels[0] = Ydata;
YUVOverlay->pixels[1] = Udata;
YUVOverlay->pixels[2] = Vdata;

SDL_DisplayYUVOverlay(YUVOverlay, dest);
```

#### Rendering loop:

```
SDL_LockYUVOverlay(YUVOverlay);
memcpy(Ydata, buffer, luma_size);
memcpy(Udata, buffer+luma_size, chroma_size);
memcpy(Vdata, buffer+luma_size+chroma_size, chroma_size);
int i = SDL_DisplayYUVOverlay(YUVOverlay, dest);
SDL_UnlockYUVOverlay(YUVOverlay);
```

The easiest fix for me to do is increase the RGB `SDL_Surface` size so that it is a multiple of 4 in each dimension. But then this adds a black border.

Is there a correct way of fixing this issue? Should I try playing with padding on my YUV data?

Comment: Originated from X-windows, many video formats align each row to double word boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each plane of your input data must start on an address divisible by 8, and the stride of each row must be divisible by 8. To be clear: your chroma planes need to obey this too.

This requirement seems to be from the SDL library's use of MMX multimedia instructions on an x86 cpu. See the comments in src/video/SDL_yuv_mmx.c in the distribution.

update: I looked at the actual assembly code, and there are additional assumptions not mentioned in the source code comments. This is for SDL 1.2.14. In addition to the modulo 8 assumption described above, the code assumes that both the input luma and input chroma planes are packed perfectly (i.e. width == stride).

Comment: Apologies for the delay in accepting this answer, I had tweaked the SDL_Surface as a stop-gap. This does appear to present a a bit of a challenge to video of dimension non-modulo 8. I suppose the simplest "correct" solution, from a programming standpoint, is to re-arrange the data to crop each line (and stride) till it is modulo 8.